# Encoding two Unix timestamps into one

Tags: javascript, url, encoding, get

My application requires a date range in a GET parameters. I was thinking there must be some genius way of encoding two Unix timestamps into one, effectively shortening the URL parameters.

I realize a simple CSV of two timestamps would do the trick, but the goal here is to reduce the URL size as much as possible.

PS: This would also need to work if there is only one date (the start date), in which case the end date will be assumed as today.

Comment: Eh, what for? I mean it is no problem to short it, but why is this important?

Comment: Because good URLs is good design

Comment: My older, more experienced self realizes good design is not obfuscating param values but having simple, explicit params instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here are a few ideas:

- If the two timestamps are likely to be close to one another, store them as a pair of the first time and the difference. For example, for now and tomorrow, you'd store `1361666257,86400`.
- Store the timestamps in hexadecimal (base 16) instead of base 10; e.g, `512960d1`
- If the timestamps are always dates, store them in terms of days since the epoch, rather than seconds, by dividing by 86400 and discarding the remainder. Today is day 15760, for instance.

And/or combine all three of these: `3d90,1`

Comment: I expanded on your base 16 idea and decided to encode my dates with base 36.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is reducing the URL size as much as possible, you can come up with your own "timestamp" format, choosing the granularity and offset at your convenience.

For example, if the dates you need to pass are usually around the current date of the request and if you only need the date and not the time of day, you could use the number of **days ago**, instead of the number of **seconds since year 1970**, which is the UNIX timestamp definition.

Here is what a random date range looks like with unix timestamps and with this variant:

```
Date range: 2012-09-21 to 2013-01-10
Timestamp:  1348178400_1357772400
Days-ago:   156_45
```

Notice I have used `_` to separate the *from* and *to* parts, because the minus sign `-` is needed for dates before 1970 when using UNIX timestamps, or dates in the future in my example encoding.

This is just an example. You should come up with your own encoding (or not) based on your application needs. For example if the date range is usually small, you could encode it as a date + a difference. The difference could be in days, or in months, or in whole years... depending on your needs.